# Execute line given in output of another command

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Warning: this question is not about usage of git, but about usage of pipes in Linux, `git` command is given here as example.

Having such output of `git push`

```
fatal: The current branch my_branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

   git push --set-upstream origin my_branch
```

I want to execute given command, i.e. `git push --set-upstream origin my_branch`.

By doing `git push 2>&1 | tail -3` I get `git push --set-upstream origin my_branch` printed on screen.

Question: What command should be added to next pipe so given `git push` will be executed. So I could do `git push 2>&1 | tail -3 | command_to_eval_given_string`

Comment: You want `tail -1`, not `tail -3` ... it's just the last one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe to `bash` itself:

```
git push ... | bash
```

This will send the stdout from the previous pipes to bash, that will then execute it.

```
$ echo "echo 'hello'" | bash
hello
$ echo "uptime" | bash
 16:22:37 up  7:31,  3 users,  load average: 0,03, 0,14, 0,23
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than piping to another command, you can instead wrap the pipeline in a command substitution and `eval` it. This will execute the command in your current shell session. For example:

```
eval "$(printf 'some output 1\nsome output 2\necho execute me'| tail -1)";
## execute me
```